# Passing parameters to Glue job from AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-glue

We need to pass 4 parameters from AWS Lambda to AWS Glue job while triggering Glue job.

```
response = client.start_job_run(JobName = 'my_test_Job',
         Arguments = {
           '--yr_partition_val':   2017,
           '--mon_partition_val':  05,
           '--date_partition_val':  25,
           '--hour_partition_val': 07 } )
```

Glue need to catch these 4 parameters to proceed further in pyspark glue code.

I have tried using below in glue to catch parameters:

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,
                      ['JOB_NAME',
                       'yr_partition_val',
                       'mon_partition_val',
                       'date_partition_val',
                       'hour_partition_val'])
```

but got the error as:

```
self.error(_('argument %s is required') % name)
awsglue.utils.GlueArgumentError: argument --JobName is required
```

Can someone help it out?

Comment: Got answer, need to add --Jobname as parameter in glue job. basically, in advanced configuration in glue job, we need to add --Jobname in key & corresponding glue job name in value. remaining things follow same as section "Passing and Accessing Python Parameters in AWS Glue" in link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-calling.html

Comment: I dont think you have to add --Jobname parameter. There must be some other issue. For me, code works without adding --Jobname parameter explicitly. `JobName = 'my_test_Job'` should add --Jobname parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [AWS says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html) `'--JOB_NAME'` is internal to Glue and should not be set.
>   Also, the arguments are case-sensitive.

**When calling from -**

> Glue API

`Name='job_name_value'` needs to be specified as first argument

> Lambda API

`JobName='job_name_value'` needs to be specified as first argument
**See Example below:**

```
    current_year_full = '2019'
    current_month = '01'
    current_day = '21' 
    current_hour = '01'
    int_bucket_name = 'datascience-ca-input'
    glue_job_name = os.getenv("job_name")
    response = gl.start_job_run(
            JobName = glue_job_name,
            Arguments = {
                '--intermediate_bucket_name': int_bucket_name,
                '--year_partition_value': current_year_full,
                '--month_partition_value': current_month,
                '--date_partition_value': current_day,
                '--hour_partition_value': current_hour } )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
glueJobName = 'job_01'
for record in event['Records']:
    print(record['s3']['object']['key'])
    file_name = unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'])
    client = boto3.client('glue')
    print("Job is going to start")
    arguments = {
        '--source': 'abc',
        '--bucket_name': 'test',
        '--folder_name': 'abc-2',
        '--file_name': file_name,
    }
    response = client.start_job_run(JobName = 'job_01', Arguments=arguments)
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps('Glue Trigger Lambda!' )
}
```